# Form Data is getting pushed in array but not displaying in UI in angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Updated question. I am pushing data in db and then in an array so that it will be displayed right away using angular 2 way binding. However my data is getting pushed in can see in the console. But it's not displaying in UI.

**Controller**

```
    contacts.getall().then(function(response){
     vm.people = response.data;
    });


    vm.toggleSidenav = function(){
      $mdSidenav('left').open();
    };


    vm.saveit = function(info){
         vm.people.push(vm.xyz); 
         contacts.add(vm.xyz);
         console.log(vm.people);
```

**My list**

```
   <md-list>
  <md-list-item  ng-repeat="person in vm.people | filter:vm.searchText |     orderBy:'name'" ng-click="showDialog($event, person)">
  <img alt="{{ person.name }}" ng-src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-nR0PNFb3p4k/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/NVt2CqCrCis/photo.jpg" class="md-avatar" />
   <p>{{ person.name }}</p>
   <p class="phn">{{ person.phone }}</p> 

<md-icon ng-click="vm.showConfirm($event, person)"aria-label="Open Chat" class="md-secondary md-hue-3" ng-class="">delete</md-icon>
 </md-list-item>

  </md-list>
```

**For console**

```
  vm.people.push(vm.xyz); 
  contacts.add(vm.xyz);
  console.log(vm.people);
```

Comment: is there an error?

Comment: No error on console.

Comment: can you create a plunker for the issue?

Comment: yes, I am creating

Answer (score 0):

--------------------------------------------------------- **Fixed Update**-------------------------------------------------------

Al-right so there is a very simple rule of Angular when you want to pass a value from one controller to another, the best way is to do is to use a Factory but since in this case you are NOT using second controller we won't be using factory.

you initialized `var vm.people = [];` as an array.

but below here you are pushing an **OBJECT** within an **ARRAY**

```
vm.people.push({
  name: vm.info.name,
  phone: vm.info.phone,
  email: vm.info.email
});
```

Which in this case is wrong thats why the scope wasn't getting updated.

what you should be doing is creating JSON object and than update your `$scope.showData`

```
vm.people = { "name": vm.info.name, "phone": vm.info.phone, "email": vm.info.email};
```

Which result in updating the current scope and save the data at the same time. the storage factory in the plunker was for testing purposes only, if you want you can remove it. but in case if you need it you know how to pass and store data in the factory and than retrieve it.

take a look at your the update fixed [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/U81uyelX3YIobiPzzvdJ?p=preview)

Animated GIF:

[image: Updating the scope in real time]

----------------------------------------------------------- **Old Reply**----------------------------------------------------------
Hey there I've made a working plunker out of your own code, the `vm.people` array which you have defined at the top and then pushing the data in it within the `vm.saveit` fucniton is working absolutely fine and as expected, `vm.people` has an object with three 3 properties, what seems to be the problem ?

```
[Object]
0
:

email: "dump@gmail.com"
name: "waqas"
phone: "4245345343"
```

Working plunker [Form Data is not getting pushed in array in angularjs](https://plnkr.co/edit/U81uyelX3YIobiPzzvdJ?p=preview)

Comment: Hi waqas, vm.saveit() is working. I am first injecting the data into db then into the angular array so that I can show it right away. But it's not working. here is the github link for controller - https://github.com/sourabh-garg/contactaap.1/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/script/controllers.js If you want to see what I am taking about just create a new record in https://flap-contact.herokuapp.com/

Comment: let me take a look

Comment: so what you are trying to say is that record is getting saved in DB but it doesn't show up on the record list on the right side unless you refresh the page ??

Comment: Yes exactly that why's I am pushing the info data into "people array". 2 way binding should work. Something I am missing.

Comment: OK let me do that for you on plunker cuz it would be difficult to explain here.

Comment: I have updated the question. I can see in console the data is getting pushed. But it's not displaying in list.

Comment: fixed it man you have made a terrible mistake let me post a detailed answer.

Comment: I am not getting it man. Your new Plunker takes me to the old one. Please update it.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/U81uyelX3YIobiPzzvdJ?p=preview This is the link, did you make an entry to see how your scope get updated right away ?

Comment: No luck till yet. This is confusing, after pushing the new object in array if I print it in console I can see a new object added.

Comment: OK tell me where exactly are you consoling and what is it you are consoling ?

Comment: I have updated the question. with console.log() . Why I am seeing the old post in plunker. I haven't used much of it. Is any settings required or anything?

Comment: dude clear your browser history and if you are seeing this Json Object you are on the right page I have updated the old page. 
vm.people = { "name": vm.info.name, "phone": vm.info.phone, "email": vm.info.email};

Comment: I'll fork your github project, fix it in your real app, once I text you here you can pull it.

Comment: Quick question how do you run the app ?

Comment: testing in local host. have hosted it in heroku

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111995/discussion-between-waqas-khan-and-scripter).